# How to get a SHA 1 certificate with java 10?

Tags: android, sha1, android-debug, java-10

I am trying to get the SHA 1 certificate with the help of this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) but I am not getting the required result with JAVA 10.

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

error: `**keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Only one command is allowed: both -exportcert and -list were specified.**`

```
keytool -exportcert -v \ -alias androiddebug -keystore C:\Users\Tushar Rai\.android\debug.keystore
```

output
**

```
Exports certificate
Options:
 -rfc                    output in RFC style
 -alias <alias>          alias name of the entry to process
 -file <file>            output file name
 -keystore <keystore>    keystore name
 -cacerts                access the cacerts keystore
 -storepass <arg>        keystore password
 -storetype <type>       keystore type
 -providername <name>    provider name
 -addprovider <name>     add security provider by name (e.g. SunPKCS11)
   [-providerarg <arg>]    configure argument for -addprovider
 -providerclass <class>  add security provider by fully-qualified class name
   [-providerarg <arg>]    configure argument for -providerclass
 -providerpath <list>    provider classpath
 -v                      verbose output
 -protected              password through protected mechanism
Use "keytool -help" for all available commands
```

This is the output after trying the command for the SHA1 certificate

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Tushar Rai\.android\debug.keystore" -v
Enter keystore password:

*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************

Android Debug10U
Android Debug10UU0
 üì 0üëüü íl°╧⌠zlù¢Güƒ0
╒g"$$°pca╔Θ!╕à]╛╚Hó[≤¡└Γê2┴╘░ªG┐ùÖ_5?7B¥K╘-£┤∞eΓ0╜┴òÄ┘ìPpPu┘m⌐δ9}Ys°Ii┘■2£τ╘c½█óR║$1xeφⁿh
 üü ô╕rV┼∩╬o╥ΣAL┐─Q╥P^d6¥ì╚kèÄí^▒K┬+ÇmPUNφ▄⌐!á8GpÄd═y²rûNú'╠x÷|┴}ê`─╬äé_▄6╚╙ìƒÆgZσⁿMS╩½Äv]µ}÷      îh┌|ä ┐ézV9?╠Åδ!τ┤|U╪²û╬fm╦⌠
Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Users\Tushar Rai\.android\debug.keystore -destkeystore C:\Users\Tushar Rai\.android\debug.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".
```

**

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the username "because it contains a space" 
try this command instead

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Tushar Rai\.android\debug.keystore" -list -v
```

edit:
this command worked for him

```
 keytool -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Tushar Rai\.android\debug.keystore" -list -v
```

Comment: yes this cmd worked after removing `-list` and now its asking for the password, its not taking the blank

Comment: I am trying to type the default password `android` but its not typing

Comment: you should write `android` ...trust me it will not typing but it will be written inside the computer ....the policy of the cmd when writing the password is like so...
we all know that it should be show ******* when writing the password but this is not the case when we try to type the password in the cmd or the terminal .....
so ...now just type that command then type `android` ...but remember that the cmd will not show you that you are typing `android`

Comment: don't forget to add the `-list` option in case it didn't work

Comment: Have a look at the question I have added the output system throws after accessing it with password `android`

Comment: I think there is some problem with the font.

Comment: make sure that you are typing in english while you are writing the password `android`

Comment: I see now what is the problem in the command...I tried to run this command on my PC and I received the same error you received ....the solution of this problem is to add the `-list` option to the command...so the command should be
  `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Tushar Rai\.android\debug.keystore" -list -v`

Comment: error `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Only one command is allowed: both -exportcert and -list were specified`

Comment: this command works `keytool -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Tushar Rai\.android\debug.keystore" -list -v`

Comment: very good ...I'm really happy because finally you could solve this problem

Comment: Welcome my friend

Answer (score 0):

to get  release key :

keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\MG\Desktop\test.jks -alias test